# User loop in Java using boolean

Tags: java, return, boolean

I am trying to figure out how to create a multi-condition answer to equal the same thing. (Example: Y y)  When I ask to use if they want to continue I want it to continue regardless of case. Any ideas?

```
public static boolean Continue() {
    char choice;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Continue(Y/N)");
    choice = input.next().charAt(0);
    return choice == 'y';      
}
```

Comment: if you only want to "continue regardless of case" you can just `return true`.

Comment: I think what you mean is regardless of upper or lower case?

Comment: Use the "or" operator: `return choice == 'y' || choice == 'Y'`

Answer (score 2):

This should suffice:

```
return Character.toLowerCase(choice) == 'y';
```

By lower-casing the choice, you only have to compare it against one value.

Answer (score 1):

You need to verify if input is 'y' *OR* 'Y', therefore **Or** condition-operator will help:

```
return choice == 'y' || choice == 'Y';
```

Comment: I feel like such a newb =( THANK YOU SO MUCH. I was using the OR condition but forgot to add "choice".

Answer (score 0):

If you are limited to alphabet from 'a' to 'Z', you can always do the lowercase yourself using `|` operator.

This is an example :

```
char i;
i = 'y';
System.out.println((i | 32) == 'y');
i = 'Y';
System.out.println((i | 32) == 'y');
```

Using the `| 32` will set the only bit different between lower and upper case letter to 1, resulting into a lowercase.

This is the same as `Character.toLowerCase` but this as more condition that are not always necessary, especially in a restricted condition.